# If $0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon), \forall \epsilon \gt 0$, then $h^{-1}(B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)) \in \tau^N$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $g:(X,N)\to (\Bbb R, N^{d_1})$ be a continuous function where $g(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in X$ and $(\Bbb R, N^{d_1})$ the eucludian topological space.

Let be the function $h=1/g$, prove:

If $0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon), \forall \epsilon \gt 0$, then $h^{-1}(B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)) \in \tau^N$.

$\textbf{Additional comments:}$

$N$ is a topological structure, $d_1$ is the usual metric in $\Bbb R$, so $N^{d_1}$ is the topological structure associated to the metric $d_1$. $\tau^N$ is the topology associated to that topological structure. And $B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)$ is the open ball with metric $d_1$ centered at $b$ of radius $\epsilon$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

I know $h$ is continuous by continuity of $g$ and $g(x) \neq 0, \forall x \in X$. As an open ball is an open set, then its preimage is open in  $\tau^N$. But I don't know how to use the hypothesis that $0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)$ and I don't how to write the proof formally.

I was thinking, as $0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon), \forall \epsilon \gt 0$ then, $b=0$ and $B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$. That implies $h^{-1}(B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon))=\emptyset$, and off course, $\emptyset \in \tau^N$.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide more details on your notation? What are $N$, $d_1$ and $\tau$? Also, is $B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon)$ the open ball centered at $b$ of radius $\epsilon$ in $d_1$ dimensions?

Comment: Your proof is ok and the hypothesis is useless. Btw, I think it should not contain "$\color{red}\forall\epsilon>0$", because "$0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon), \forall \epsilon \gt 0$" is equivalent to $b=0$.

Comment: Juan, you should edit your post to insert all this.

Comment: @AnneBauval I already edited my post. Is my attempt ok?

Comment: Ok only until "then, $b=0$" ($B_{d_1}(0,\epsilon)\supsetneq\lbrace 0 \rbrace$), and except the weird hypothesis "$0 \in B_{d_1}(b,\epsilon), \forall \epsilon \gt 0$" in the statement you were asked to prove. Again, such an hypothesis (even replaced by something more sensible) is useless.